# can you gzip with zlib compression off

Tags: php, compression, gzip, shared-hosting

I am really trying to get up to speed with website optimization as most off my websites really lack in speed. I am using http://gtmetrix.com/ to test my website speed.

One thing I really need to do is use gzip compression. I spent ages trying to get it to work and could not figure out where i was going wrong.

If I click more information in web developer toolbar it said gzip enabled so this was decieving as it isn’t. I contacted my hosting providers and got the following response:

> Unfortunately not, Gzip would cause too much load on our hosted
>   servers therefore any similar programs would cause the same strain.

So even when it says it is enabled, I think I am right in saying what you need to check for in the php.ini file is:

```
zlib.output_compression        Off       Off
zlib.output_compression_level  -1        -1
zlib.output_handler            no value  no value
```

Ok, so I assume this needs to be set to on to allow gzip compression. Is this correct?

Basically I would have to go for a dedicated server to allow for gzip £70 a month.

So I guess what I am asking is: Is there a way using PHP to utillise gzip compression without it being enabled by the hosting provider? I have tried many option but none successful so far.

Thanks

Comment: from the **faq**: When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer. This lets other people know that you have received a good answer to your question. Doing this is helpful because it shows other people that you're getting value from the community. (If you don't do this, people will often politely ask you to go back and accept answers for more of your questions!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gzip/deflate adds no significant load. Those rip-off prices aren't worth it however.

As for PHP, it can also be enabled from within scripts:

```
ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
```

Would be emulatable via gzencode() if not available; but too much overhead I'd assume..

Comment: Hi Mario sorry does this mean that it is possible to apply some gzip compression to my files, without zlib.output_compression on, i have tried a lot off scripts but the load time for my site doesn't change still end up with a D when putting the site through http://gtmetrix.com/. The thing i am finding about wordpress website is when using lots of plugins you get so many js file and extra css file it really slows things down, has anyone had any experience with this and may now how to deal with page speed without gzip?

Comment: @iSimpleDesign: That's nothing were gzip will help. Use mod_pagespeed or do it manually. Or getafreelancer if you can't manage yourself. -- Also: look into your Stackoverflow profile, visit old questions, and accept answers.